# Can't Uninstall "asciidoc" Package

Tags: uninstall, 19.10, asciidoc

I was building from source a package which needed asciidoc on Ubuntu 19.10. Now I want to uninstall it but I get the following

```
Package 'asciidoc' is not installed, so not removed
```

while it is clearly installed. Why is that happening? How can I uninstall it?

Comment: Please add output of `which asciidoc` and `dpkg -S $(which asciidoc)` to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main `asciidoc` executable in 18.04 LTS and newer versions is [located](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fasciidoc&mode=exactfilename&suite=eoan&arch=any) in `asciidoc-base` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/all/asciidoc-base/filelist).

You have to remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge asciidoc-base
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

For source code installations, here are the install/uninstall commands...

**Installing asciidoc for all users**

Create configure using autoconf(1); use configure to create the Makefile; run make(1); build the man pages; install:

```
$ autoconf
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

**To uninstall:**

```
$ sudo make uninstall
```

**Source**: http://asciidoc.org/INSTALL.html

**Update #1**

For binary installations...

```
dpkg -l *ascii* | grep ii

un asciidoc <none> <none> (no description available) 
ii asciidoc-base 8.6.10-3 all Minimal version of asciidoc not suitable for pdf 
ii asciidoc-common 8.6.10-3 all Basic data and configuration files for asciidoc un asciidoc-doc <none> <none> (no description available)
```

To completely uninstall asciidoc, you'll need to run all of these commands...

```
sudo apt-get purge asciidoc # already done

sudo apt-get purge asciidoc-base

sudo apt-get purge asciidoc-common
```

Comment: I haven't installed it from source, the command `sudo apt purge asciidoc` should work fine, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Adam Show me `dpkg -l *ascii* | grep ii`.

Comment: @Adam Status please...

Comment: un  asciidoc        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  asciidoc-base   8.6.10-3     all          Minimal version of asciidoc not suitable for pdf
ii  asciidoc-common 8.6.10-3     all          Basic data and configuration files for asciidoc
un  asciidoc-doc    <none>       <none>       (no description available)